# Discretizing a formula for simulation

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry, discrete-calculus

I have some molecules in different positions of a plane. Each molecule has a number which is shown by $\hat{f}$.
I want to find an continues field is written as:

$\int |\nabla \cdot f|^2 d^2r$.

Integration is the whole plane. I need to discretize formula and sum over different molecules. But I don't know how to do that. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\bf #1}}$

> Smoothing the density

I will assume that you have $N$ molecules each at a location $\vect{r}_j\in \Omega$, we can define the density at an arbitrary location $\vect{r}$ as the weighted sum of the masses of the $N$ molecules. Of course, this weight is distance dependent: the farther a molecule is, the smaller is its contribution

$$
\rho(\vect{r}) = \sum_{j = 1}^N m_j W_h(|\vect{r} - \vect{r}_j|) \tag{1}
$$

where $W_h\in C^{(1)}(\Omega)$ is then a decaying function of $r = |\vect{r}|$ with finite support, in this case is of size $h$. Below I give a possible choice for $W_h$, in the mean time, note that it must satisfy

$$
\sum_j m_j = M(\Omega) = \int_\Omega{\rm d}\Omega ~\rho(\vect{r}) = \sum_jm_j\int_\Omega{\rm d}\Omega W_h(|\vect{r} - \vect{r}_j|) ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ 2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}r ~rW_h(r) = 1 \tag{2}
$$

where I assume that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, but clearly you can extend this to the dimensions you want. Now, with equation (1) you can calculate the density associated to any molecule $i$

$$
\rho(\vect{r}_i) = \sum_{j = 1}^N m_j W_h(|\vect{r}_i - \vect{r}_j|) \tag{3}
$$

The size of the kernel is usually calculated as the distance $h$ that encloses the $k$-th nearest neighbor of the particle $i$. From my experience this is the slowest part of the algorithm, but can be done really efficiently in $\mathcal{O}(N\log N)$.

> Smoothing the field

In general any field can be written as

$$
f(\vect{r}) = \sum_j m_j \frac{f_j}{\rho_j}W_h(|\vect{r} - \vect{r}_j|) \tag{4}
$$

In particular $f = \{n_x, n_y\}$. Now it is a matter of calculating integrals, just note that

$$
\nabla f(\vect{r}) = \sum_j m_j \frac{f_j}{\rho_j}\nabla W_h(|\vect{r} - \vect{r}_j|) = \sum_j m_j \frac{f_j}{\rho_j}\frac{\vect{r} - \vect{r}_j}{|\vect{r} - \vect{r}_j|}W_h'(|\vect{r} - \vect{r}_j|) \tag{5}
$$

I will leve the rest to you, $\nabla \times \vect{n} = (\ldots)$

> The smothing kernel $W_h$

This is one popular choice
$$
W_h(x) = \frac{10}{7\pi h^2}\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
1 - (3/2)z^2(1 - z^2/2) & 0 \leq z = x/h < 1 \\
(2 - z)^3/4 & 1 \leq z = x/h < 2 \\
0 & z = x/h \geq 2 \end{array} \right.
$$

> Python-Module

If you're familiar with python you can try [pysph](http://pysph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), it implements all the equations above in a fairly transparent way

Comment: What are h and j in the last relation?

Comment: is the calculation of derivative correct? I think f and $\rho$ are also a function of distance and should be considered when calculating the gradient. Am I correct?

Comment: @SoniaSohi $h= h_i$ the distance that encloses the $k$-th nearest neighbor of the particle $i$. This each particle has its own $h$. You can select $k=64$, this usually gives good results

Comment: @SoniaSohi No, $f_j$ and $\rho_j$ do not depend on the position, these are properties associated with particle $j$. For instance, $f_j = n_{x,j}$ is the $x$-component of the direction of particle $j$. And $\rho_j$ is calculated as $\rho_j = \rho({\bf r}_j)$ (see Eq. 3)

Comment: I have only 100 molecules. Do you think it makes the method more precise if I choose k=100? Does it usually work well if one chooses k equal to N?

Comment: $\nabla \times n = (\partial n_x/\partial y - \partial n_y / \partial x) \hat{z}$ in 2D. Each partial derivative is basically a component of Eq. (5)

Comment: @SoniaSohi The larger $k$, the smoothest the results. Usually you don't want to use $ k =N$, try with 32 particles first

Comment: If "The larger kk, the smoothest the results"is correct, why do you say its better to try k=32?

Comment: @SoniaSohi You do not want to smooth out all features in the field ${\bf n}$, but not want it to be dominated by noise either. A good compromise I think is $k = 32$, but you have to try it out

Comment: I persist on choosing k=N, because if so, always the first condition (0<z<1) is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65841/discussion-between-sonia-sohi-and-caverac).

Comment: Sorry, one more question: how many points in space is needed to do integration? I have 800 molecules in a box with length equal to 250

Comment: @SoniaSohi you want to resolve the smallest $h$ with your quadrature

Comment: you mean mesh size for integration is equal to smallest h? @caverac

Comment: @SoniaSohi Even smaller, try $h/4$

Comment: My system contains 800 molecules a box with length equal to 240. Which means average distance between molecules is 8. do you thing h/4 is a good choice for this system? @caverac

Comment: @SoniaSohi How much is ${\min}\{h\}$?

Comment: 16 but it changes by time@caverac